# About natbib and chapter number

Tags: natbib

I'm using a `\chapterstyle{tandh}` because I want my chapters numbered. In order to get a References chapter numbered as well I used the following code:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{%
\chapter{\bibname}}
```

That worked fine, I got my References chapter numbered!!

But now, in order to get my references in a author-year style I'm using the `natbib` package.
Seems like the package ignores my code and the References chapter is not numbered anymore.

Can someone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you

Comment: oops.. sorry... first time :P

Comment: I solved it! I've placed the code inside of `\begin{document}` {was in preamble} and worked.

Comment: @Ana: Hi Ana, welcome to TeX.sx! `:)` You can either write your comment as an answer (self-answers are welcome!), or we could close the question as localized (it means, in this case, the cause was a simple misplacement). `:)` By the way, Brazilian? `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Hi. I just commented in case of anyone having the same trouble. You can close for sure! And yes, I'm from Brazil. Does my bad english betrayed me? :P

Comment: @Ana: Since egreg provided a nice answer, there's no need to close this question anymore. `:)` And don't worry, your English is very good! It always nice to see a fellow Brazilian around, make yourself at home! `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `natbib` package redefines `\bibsection` at begin document, in order to override other possible settings.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{duck,
 author={Duck, Donald},
 title={Ducks and friends},
 journal={J. Ducks},
 year={2012},
 pages={1-20}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{memoir}
\chapterstyle{tandh}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter{\bibname}}
}


\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Ducks}

\cite{duck}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Use `\AtBeginDocument` as indicated.

Note: the `filecontents*` environment is only for having a self contained example. Use normally your own bib file.

[image]