# Make References title bold in apa6 class document (using natbib)

Tags: macros, natbib, apa6

I'd like the References title to be bold. My MWE is below. If you comment-out the `\usepackage{natbib}` (and following line) the problem doesn't occur. Assuming  `natbib` is causing this, I thought adding

`\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\textbf{References}}`

should correct this, but no change is made.

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6} 

\usepackage{natbib} % to change citation/references/bibliography style 
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\textbf{References}}


\begin{document}

See \cite{smith} and \cite{simpson}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Smith, 2002]{smith}
Smith, F. (2002).
\newblock {\em Title}.
\newblock Publisher Name.

\bibitem[Simpson, 2002]{simpson}
Simspon, P. (2002).
\newblock {\em Title}.
\newblock Publisher Name.

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

this prints:

[image]

**Edit/solution:** I found the solution from the article linked in the comment, However, it's not an exact duplicate as I am not using the `book` class, so the solution is slightly different (the linked article uses `\bibname` while I should use `\refname`. Anyway, here's the solution for my problem:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6} 

\usepackage{natbib} % to change citation/references/bibliography style 
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section\refname}}


\begin{document}

See \cite{smith} and \cite{simpson}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Smith, 2002]{smith}
Smith, F. (2002).
\newblock {\em Title}.
\newblock Publisher Name.

\bibitem[Simpson, 2002]{simpson}
Simspon, P. (2002).
\newblock {\em Title}.
\newblock Publisher Name.

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116785/21891

Comment: @Jubobs I was able to solve my problem using that article. 

I changed the `\renewcommand...` line to `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section\bibname}}` to solve my problem.